# Creating a Web Part to display Site Owner Group Members via CSOM

Tags: 2013, csom

Does anyone have an example of displaying members of the `Site Owners` group on a SharePoint Page using CSOM?  I'd like to have this show like a web part for each Site in SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

**Out of the box**

You can use out of the box Site Users Web Part.

Add this web part and edit properties, then choose `Show People In The Group` and set the group you want to display.

**Custom Code**

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection ';

function retrieveAllUsersInGroup() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var collGroup = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();
    var oGroup = collGroup.getById(7);
    this.collUser = oGroup.get_users();
    clientContext.load(collUser);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    var userInfo = '';
    var userEnumerator = collUser.getEnumerator();
    while (userEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oUser = userEnumerator.get_current();
        this.userInfo += '\nUser: ' + oUser.get_title() + 
            '\nID: ' + oUser.get_id() + 
            '\nEmail: ' + oUser.get_email() + 
            '\nLogin Name: ' + oUser.get_loginName();
    }
    alert(userInfo);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185012(v=office.14).aspx